# Can someone identify the following key equations in physics?

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics

I need help identifying the following equations in physics. Most equations are related to quantum mechanics, a few is from relativity and electromagnetism.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Just a note that these are on the first page of Srednicki's book Quantum Field Theory. They are stated as prerequisite equations that one needs to understand to study QFT. @MathNewb, perhaps you should go ahead and learn the prerequisite physics to QFT before diving straight into the subject as this is just a sampling of what you need to understand before undertaking QFT.

Comment: Second from the bottom is from special relativity. On a side note, is this on-topic here?

Comment: No, this is a question about concepts of physics, for which there is an entire alternate SE site.${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: My only concern is that this isn't about a specific physics concept, but is simply identifying equations, in which case it might not be on-topic there, either.

Comment: It can easily be answered through a simple google search regardless of what site it's on. However, it's still more on-topic there than here.

Comment: Well, I know where all these equations come from, more or less, so maybe I should write up an answer.  But before doing so, I would like to say that I think this question is OK for MSE, in the sense that it exposes to the readers some very substantial material which has considerable mathematical import and some of which has historically motivated significant mathematical developments.  I'm interested in see how others weigh in on this question.  New Years Cheer to One and All.

Comment: @theage:  what you said about google searching is true enough I grant you, but an answer might save the OP (and conceivably others) a *lot* of time.

Comment: Okay, fair enough. I think a question about the mathematical developments coming from such equations (eg. about the abstract groups that arise when talking about angular momentum) would make a great question, but this is specifically asking for physical interpretations of equations.

Comment: Should "identify this list of things" be on-topic?

Comment: Related question on Phys.SE: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12528/2451

Comment: @theage:  But it seems to me that knowing the background or as you put it "interpretation" of such equations can only serve to enhance understanding of their mathematical relevance . . .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I like a quiz so I'll have a go:

The first one is an equation related to [scattering cross section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scattering_cross-section).

Second one is quantum mechanics: a [creation operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creation_and_annihilation_operators) acting on a state giving a new state.

Third one is quantum mechanics: the [angular momentum operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_momentum_operator) acting on a state giving a new state.

Forth one is the relation between an operator in the [Schrodinger picture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_picture) vs the [Heisenberg picture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_picture).

Number five is the equation for the [Hamiltonian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_mechanics#Calculating_a_Hamiltonian_from_a_Lagrangian) (see also [Hamiltonian in QM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_%28quantum_mechanics%29)).

Number six is [special relativity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_relativity). The relation between time and space coordinates in two frames moving relative to each other.

Number seven is an equation for the [relativistic energy](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/relativ/releng.html) of a particle.

Number eight is the relation for the electric field in terms of the [four-potential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_four-potential).

Comment: Very nicely done, ***plus one***!  Love the way you incorporated the references; *that* might *really* be helpful to our OP!

Comment: The link you give for Hamiltonian shouldn't specifically go to quantum mechanics. The equation is the definition of [classical Hamiltonian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_mechanics#Calculating_a_Hamiltonian_from_a_Lagrangian) as calculated via Legendre transformation.